# Echo value from user input PHP

Tags: php, html

I try to write HTML to file, everything is working fine but im not able to insert string based on user input into it - can you please tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = 'content.html';
$title = $_POST ['title'];
$content = '<li class="level-2"> <a class="level-2a" href="#">';
$content .= echo $title;
$content .= '
                      Lorem</a>
                       <div class="contentlevel2">
                        <span class="contentlilevel-2">
                            <!--ONEPAGECMS-START-';
$content .= echo $title;
$content .='


                            -->
                           Lorem Ipsum Doran....
                        <!--ONEPAGECMS-END-->
                  </span>
                </div>
                </li>';
file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1 class="text-center">Create new project</h1>
     <form action="project.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Project title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create project">

        </form>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content .= echo $title;
```

should just be

```
$content .= $title;
```

your creating a string, echo outputs to 'screen'

also: `$title = $_POST ['title'];` no space between T and [ (it will work it's just a little odd)